# Set SKSpriteNode with SKTexture inside the Level Editor SWIFT

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, xcode8, sktexture

I have a very large background image. So to improve my game performance, I would like to use Texture asset instead of an Image asset.

I use the Xcode 8 level editor, I don't find where set my SKSpriteNode with my Texture in the Attribute Inspector.

Is it possible to set the texture inside the level editor? My texture doesn't appear in the Texture select box.

[image]

I tried programmatically:

```
self.background = childNode(withName: "background") as! SKSpriteNode
self.background.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "backgroundTexture")
```

but it doesn't work.

EDIT

Indeed I have a warning :

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource: "backgroundTexture"
```

Comment: did you put your texture inside the image assets folder? XCode does not scan the entire project for texture files

Comment: Yes, my texture is in the xcassets folder.